# How to populate camunda html form Select from Json

Tags: camunda

I am trying to populate camunda html form select from `json` sent from my external service client.
Here is my sent json -

```
{myData=[{"id":1,"name":"This is one","value":"value11","localName":"this is local name 11"},{"id":2,"name":"This is Two","value":"value22","localName":"this is local name 22"}]}
```

Here is my html form -

```
<form>
<div>
        <select
                cam-variable-type="String"
                cam-variable-name="selected_option"
                ng-options="item as item.name for item in myData track by item.id"
                ng-model="selected"
                class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>



    <script cam-script type="text/form-script">


  camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
    // tell the form SDK to fetch the variable named 'myData'
    camForm.variableManager.fetchVariable('myData');

  });
  camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
    // work with the variable (bind it to the current AngularJS $scope)
    $scope.myData = camForm.variableManager.variableValue('myData');
  });

</script>
</form>
```

But it is coming up like below as undefined -
[image]

And i can see my `json` `myData` in next step and it's values -
[image]

Any help on how to populate my html form select from my json myData
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should parse your process variable, because it has String type

```
$scope.myData = JSON.parse(camForm.variableManager.variableValue('myData'));
```

Without parsing your select ng-options ran through every letter in your string, that's why you had so many options in select instead of two. Also you didn't set correct id for ng-options. It must be like this:

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in myData track by item.id"
```